# Url in magento product page not showing up right

Tags: magento-1.9, url, menu, product-urls

As mentioned in the title i am dealing with the following problem.
When i click at a category in my menu the url i see is something like that:

```
myshop.com/catalog/category/view/s/category-name/id/14
```

and what i want to show as url is the following

`myshop.com/menu item/category/product //(when clicked in a product).`

Any ideas?

Comment: please index from Re index from admin managemet

Comment: i did that but the problem remains. I also use varnish, is there a possibility that varnish makes some kind of conflict??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truncate your `core_url_rewrite` table and go to System → Index Management check all and select re-index.

You mention that you use varnish, make sure you empty your entire cache (SSH: `rm -rf var/cache/*`) and then try re-navigate through your catalogue.

You should now be seeing [SEO-friendly URLs](http://moz.com/learn/seo/url).

Comment: did that also and the problem still remains!