# Friendly product url

Tags: url, product-urls

I have made the following changes:

1) System > Configuration > Web > “Use Web Server Rewrites” to Yes

2)  System > Configuration > Catalog > “Use Categories Path for Product URLs” to YES

3) System > Configuration > Catalog > “Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories” to Yes

4) System > Web > Search Engine Optimization -> Use Web Server Rewrites to Yes

5) System > Catalog -> Search Engine optimizations -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs -> to NO

Now I have the situation, when i click on product a get the following friendly url: **www.domain.com/name-of-the-product**, which is what I want to archive.

Also I use the following code on my view page to display related products from same category.

```
<!--Related products-->
    <?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?> 
    <?php $result = array(); 
    foreach($categories as $cat_id) { 
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
    $category->load($cat_id); 
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $product) { 
    $result[] = $product->getId(); 
    } 
    } 
    ?> 
<div class="related-prod-conteiner"> 
    <ul class="r-prod-list-horizontal"> 
        <?php if(sizeof($result) >= 5) 
        { 
        $ourneed = array_rand($result,5); 
        foreach($ourneed as $cc) 
        { 
        $thisproduct= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($result[$cc]); 
        ?> 
            <li> 
                <div class="item-content-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo $thisproduct->getProductUrl()?>"><img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($thisproduct, 'thumbnail')->resize(150, 150)?>" alt="<?php echo $thisproduct->getName()?>"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="item-content-name"> 
                    <a href="<?php echo $thisproduct->getProductUrl()?>">
                    <h2 class="product-name">
                        <div class="three-dots-3">
                            <span class='ellipsis_text'><?php echo $thisproduct->getName()?></span>
                        </div>
                    </h2>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="item-content-price"> 
                    <?php
                    $product_block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product;
                    echo $product_block->getPriceHtml($thisproduct);
                    unset($product_block)
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="item-content-rate">
                    <?php echo $this->_reviewsHelperBlock->getSummaryHtml($thisproduct, short); ?>
                </div>
            </li> 
        <?php } ?> 
        <?php }else { 
        foreach($result as $cc) 
        { 
        $thisproduct= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($cc); 
        ?> 
        <li> 
        <a href="<?php echo $thisproduct->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $thisproduct->getName(); ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($thisproduct, 'small_image')->resize(200) ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="<?php echo $thisproduct->getName(); ?>" /></a> </li> 
        <?php } 
        } 
        ?> 
    </ul> 
</div>
    <!--/Related products-->
```

Above code works just fine, but when I click on the product which is displayed by above code, a I'm getting the following link: **www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/234/s/name-of-the-product**

I would like to display it as **www.domain.com/name-of-the-product**

thanks

Comment: When you create the product do you specify the URL key?

Comment: It is automatically generated from the name of the product

Comment: what version of magento are you using?

Comment: Did you check this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65340/url-in-magento-product-page-not-showing-up-right

Comment: Yes it might be a reindexing problem. Reindex your site and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: I just cleared the cache and reindex all my data. Nothing worked. :(

Comment: For the System > Configuration > Web > Use Web Server Rewrites make sure you have it set as default and not a specific store level.

Comment: Have tried your suggestion. Sorry, but did not work. I have noticed a new scenario. This only happens  when I click on a product from category/list/grid view. When I click on the product from my home/index web page everything seems to be ok. I assume this could be the problem of the code i have above.

Comment: Maybe something with the getProductUrl?

Answer (score 2):

I assumed this could be the reason of the get productUrl and i found the solution, which is:

instead of **getProductUrl** use **getUrlPath()**